# Why does the trailing slash on the target confuse robocopy?

Tags: robocopy

Why does the following robocopy command get confused? Remove the trailing slash from the dest ("S:\Temp Backup") and it works as expected.

> robocopy "S:\Temp\" "S:\Temp Backup\" /mir /ndl /mt /r:0

Output:

[image]

It causes the parser to include the options as part of the dest string. The main reason for asking is if you use tab completion with PowerShell, it sticks a trailing slash on the directory. Same problem happens in cmd.exe so not a PowerShell quirk.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50499/when-should-i-use-a-trailing-slash-on-a-directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does the trailing slash on the target confuse robocopy?

[Because `\` is being treated as an escape character](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

This applies to both the source and destination paths, but only when used in conjunction with a folder surrounded by double quotes (with or without spaces in the file name). The final (incorrect) string literal `"` is plainly visible when encountering this problem.

The source path version of this issue complains that a destination path hasn't been specified (since any destination path is included in the improperly escaped source path).

Solutions to this issue include using:

- No double quotes (assuming there are no spaces in the path).
- No trailing `\` (ex. `C:\path\to\folder`)
- Double trailing `\\` (ex. `C:\path\to\folder\\`)
- Trailing `\.` (ex. `C:\path\to\folder\.`)

Comment: I hadn't a clue that robocopy even *had* escape characters! Makes perfect sense now. I've wrapped robocopy in a generic PowerShell script so a bit of regex/string manipulation strips the trailing backslash